# How to Convert model.fit_generator to model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, training-data

I have codes in the following:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1/255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    vertical_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2)

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/My Drive/Harvard Medical Dataset2', target_size=(224,224), color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True, subset='training', batch_size=10, class_mode='categorical')

val_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/My Drive/Harvard Medical Dataset2', target_size=(224,224), color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True, subset='validation', batch_size=10, class_mode='categorical')

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#Found 122 images belonging to 2 classes.
#Found 30 images belonging to 2 classes.

print(train_generator.n)
print(train_generator.batch_size)
print(242//32)

#122
#10
#7
step_size_train=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator, steps_per_epoch=step_size_train, epochs=80,  verbose=1, validation_data=val_generator)
```

Then, WARNING:tensorflow:From :2: Model.fit_generator (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use Model.fit, which supports generators.

Now model.fit_generator is deprecated, what is the proper way to change model.fit_generator to model.fit in this case, PLEASE?

Comment: Have you tried `model.fit`... (as the warning suggests)?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the tensorflow documentation:  [Model.fit()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

In the Model.fit() method if you want to use a generator you pass it to the x paramater and leave y empty.
for example:

```
model.fit(x = train_generator, epochs=30, verbose = 1)
```

Hope I could help!